# Blazor Virtualize then run JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have a `Virtualize` table that does exactly what it needs to do and does it great. I now have the need to add a tooltip/popover to certain rows. This is not difficult, but I am noticing that it will not get the JavaScript portion of the setup for these tooltips to run. It seems like when I click in the table somewhere it realizes things have changed and calls the JS setup function. At that point it works great.

```
<Virtualize @ref="RowsVirtualizerLeft" ItemsProvider="RowsLoader" Context="row" ItemSize="RowHeight">
  <ItemContent>
    ...
```

And the loader:

```
public async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<VirtualizedRow>> RowsLoader(ItemsProviderRequest request)
{
  var result = BodyRows
    .Where(x => x.IsVisible);

  return new ItemsProviderResult<VirtualizedRow>(
    result
      .Skip(request.StartIndex)
      .Take(request.Count),
      result.Count()
  );
}
```

The overridden `OnAfterRender` event:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setupPopovers");
}
```

And lasty the JavaScript method:

```
function setupPopovers() {
  const triggers = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='swift-trigger-']");

  triggers.forEach((trig) => {
    ...
```

That is until I scroll down the dataset to a new area of data. These new rows also need to be "setup" and are not. It seems like any interaction on the table (like the click) will alert Blazor to call the `OnAfterRenderAsyn` which in turn calls me JS setup function and those tooltips now work.

So, my question is, is there a way to know when the UI is done rendering from the `Virtualize` component? I am not seeing an event I can catch from it? I suppose at worst, I could make a call that is paused for a second and then does the setup, but that does not seem to be a guarantee to always be enough time. Not like I would want to slow the app down either.

Is there a JavaScript page event I can catch that knows when things are done rendering? Perhaps whatever JavaScript Microsoft is doing has a way to catch an event from there?

***More Info***

I am not able to add any third party projects to the solution. So the suggestion by @Vikram-reddy will not work. We have the Bootstrap 5 (css only, not JS) and Popper.js. Plus whatever we write ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const triggers = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='swift-trigger-']");
```

The tooltip will not work in a virtualization scenario.

Please try the below component from **BlazorBootstrap**.

Demo: https://demos.getblazorbootstrap.com/tooltips 
Github: https://github.com/vikramlearning/blazorbootstrap

Sample Code:

```html
<Tooltip Title="Tooltip Left" Placement="TooltipPlacement.Left">Tooltip Left</Tooltip>
```

**OR**

Use the below approach on each row when it renders

```html
var exampleTriggerEl = document.getElementById('example')
var tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getOrCreateInstance(exampleTriggerEl)
tooltip.show();
```

Comment: We are limited on what 3rd party components we can use. So, I am not able to add BlazorBootstrap to our solution. The code I have works, but it is as if it needs to be awoken. Thank you for your reply.